# I get a timeout error after clicking a button (not a page load) in Selenium for Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, timeout

I get a timeout error after clicking a button (not a page load) in Selenium for Java. The button triggers a recalculation and causes the cursor to spin and be unavailable for the 5-6 minutes until the calculation has completed.

I have added these lines to try and extend the wait time, but it has not helped:

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(300));
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300));
    driver.manage().timeouts().scriptTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300));
```

These should give me 5 minutes before triggering the error, but I get a time out at 3 minutes.

I have seen other answers that suggest adding a wait statement after the click statement, however, this will not work because the test fails before it could get to and execute that wait (the click statement still is active, and the test fails).

I believe that since it is failing at 3 minutes (and the wait statements are set at 5), this is unrelated to the standard wait strategies, and there must be some other method to adjust the timeout for longer running processes within tests. Please help me out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually provide a sample of your click action and the code directly after it to provide enough information for people to work with in my opinion.

As a workaround for now you could implement a thread sleep directly after clicking the button, which should guarantee your wait. This is however not exactly ideal.

```
try {
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(7);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```